# Spring Security Cors configuration not setting any headers

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

Applying cors configuration to Spring Security configuration is not working. There are no headers applied thus giving me cors error on web browsers.

Current security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private ApiKeyAuthFilter apiKeyAuthFilter;
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors(x -> x.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .sessionManagement(sessionManagement -> sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .addFilterBefore(apiKeyAuthFilter, HeaderWriterFilter.class)
            .authorizeHttpRequests((x) -> x
                    .requestMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().denyAll()
            );
        return http.build();
    }


     @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(false);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

I'm expecting it to apply the configured cors so I can make requests from browsers to my api. I have tried setting the headers manually using a filter and using `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)` on both controller class and methods.

Edit:

cors error

```
User
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8083/api/v1/payment' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Comment: Ok. Now inspect the preflight request in your browser. Does it contain an `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header? If so, you'll need to allow the header names listed there in your CORS configuration.

Comment: Access-Control-Request-Headers should be configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*")); and the * is any but the header isn't added to the response. It's as if .cors(x -> x.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())) is ignored...

Comment: Are you even sure that your configuration class is loaded by spring security? Enable DEBUG logs and show us your startup logs including your request

Comment: You can also try disabling CORS completely to ensure that your conf is loaded

Comment: @jw9832hds Show your custom filter implementation.